# php sessions not transferring between pages

Tags: php, session

Okay so I am not entirely sure why this isn't working but any insight would be helpful . I am making a html web form with php as back end and it's spread out over multiple pages, So my paln is to use a php session to helkp sync data for a user with data in databse between pages (not storing all the form data in session)
so i Have this code after first section of form has been entered in database

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["session_id"]=$this_session;
include 'form-page-2.php';
```

where $this_session is just a microtime stamp in php;
and then on form-page-2.php when handling input data I use this to try and get this info back:

```
$this_session =  $_SESSION["session_id"];
```

and I get the error `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\Karen-forms\form-page-2.php on line 30` however if i do a `vardump($_SESSION);` on I get the expected value I would expect

```
  array (size=1)
    'session_id' => string '1390976355.1481' (length=15)`
```

so How cqan I properly pull out the session_id one form-page-2.php as clearly I am doiing something wrong just unsure as to what
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is the line no 30?

Comment: Put `session_start();` on top of that file.

Comment: session_start(); should be the first line of code on all page where you want to get or set any session variable

Comment: check this line `$this_session =  $_SESSION["session_id"]; ` it seems that you have `$this_session =  _SESSION["session_id"]; ` as your error says

Comment: @rikesh copy and paste this into an answer in the next bit and I will accept you were first to give this advice so I'd like to reward you thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call function `session_start()` on top of all pages where you use session.

> When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will
> call the open and read session save handlers. These will either be a
> built-in save handler provided by default or by PHP extensions (such
> as SQLite or Memcached); or can be custom handler as defined by
> session_set_save_handler(). The read callback will retrieve any
> existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will
> be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION
> superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back
> to PHP session handling.

**Source:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php